# Load balancing issue during performance testing

Tags: performance-testing, internal-load-balancer

A strange observation from a recent test. Any direction would really help. 2 load balanced presentation servers are showing cpu usage moving in opposite direction i.e. 1 node reaches 100% gradually while the other node cpu usage decreases after test is started. The next day test, same pattern was seen but node 2 was reaching 100% but node 1 usage decreased.  From F5 we can see connections are nearly equal in both nodes. F5 rule is round robin.

Comment: what if work-1 is 100 cycles, work-2 is 1000 cycles, work-3 is 100 cycles, work-4 is 1000 cycles?

Comment: What kind of transactions you have? I suppose that it's possible to have 2 operations: a common one that can be predicted + another one that is different every time.